# How can one open Visual Studio login prompt without Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to login to Visual Studio Team Services from Dynamics NAV using a .dll i've made. When i'm testing my .dll through a console application the Visual Studio login prompt shows up just fine:

[image: VS login showing correctly]

However when i try to do the same thing in Dynamics NAV, a different environment, the login prompt doesn't show at all.

These are the lines in my code that make the prompt show up.

```
VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
        creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();
```

As i am forcing the session to be authenticated, and i never get to input my credentials, i get a 401 unauthorized error.

What can be happening here? Is there any way i can open this login prompt without Visual Studio?

**Edit**: sometimes the error i get from NAV is the following:

> A call to Navi.Navi.CheckIn failed with this message: Method not
>   found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.get_SerializerSettings()'.

I also got this error when i tried starain's answer. AND i have the RunOnClient property set to 'Yes'.

I'm starting to think NAV just doesn't allow the execution of this login prompt or doesn't have access to it. I'm just looking for a secure way of handling authentication without having to resort to alternate credentials or tokens.

Comment: Make sure the variable you are using in Nav is set to `RunOnClient = true`

Comment: Try it with  this code: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AresBGZVYryjhSuxr7EA3mAvFF8h

Comment: Also, try it with TaskFactory.StartNew method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: With this error I'd assume that you have problem with dependencies. Nav already have a JSON library in it so it is loaded on start (most probably) from installation folder. Maybe this version of the library doesn't contain required method. So when your dll is loaded it just uses wrong version of JSON lib just because it is already loaded into memory. Parameters you can play with is in `Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.exe.config` file in the `assemblyBinding` tag. Or you need to implement your own resolver.

Comment: Or you could try to replace Nav's JSON lib with newer version. Not sure if Nav will live with it.

Comment: @sonicadv27 My code has the logical to get work item, what's the result if you just connect to VSTS (remove get work item logical and return void)